# DynamoDB scan table with filter expression

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to scan a table and return all entries which match my filter expression. I've got an API Gateway which accepts a GET-Request that contains a starting time and a end time. (Format: [dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss]
The database im scanning has an attribute called "timestamp" in the same format. I've tried it with the filter

```
Timestamp BETWEEN :date1 and :date2
```

date1 and date2 represent the starting and ending time from the API. Timestamp is the field in my Database.
Unfortunately the scan doesnt return any values.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date format has to be in [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) string format for you to be able to scan on it. [You can see this in the documentation here, under the "String" category](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypes).